# Validate the response from JDBC request using beanshell or JSR223

Tags: jmeter

For my JDBC request, the following result I am receiving from Oracle DB and want to validate the response should not give more than `1` records and `EVENT_LOG_ID=48144960`

```
AUDIT_CONTEXT_KEY,              EVENT_LOG_VALUE, EVENT_LOG_ID, EVENT_LOGGED_DTTM
72454_2021-09-16T07:44:41.439Z  ENG_SITE         48144960      16-SEP-21 07.44.43.456000000 AM
```

**Config Details:**
[image]

**Result Details:**
[image]

Debugger Sampler Result:

```
dataFromDB=[{EVENT_LOG_VALUE=ENG_SITE, EVENT_LOG_ID=48144960, EVENT_LOGGED_DTTM=2021-09-16 07:44:43.456, AUDIT_CONTEXT_KEY=72454_2021-09-16T07:44:41.439Z}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a JSR223 Assertion with the following code, this will validate what you are looking for,

```
1.upto(vars.get('AUDIT_CONTEXT_KEY_#') as int, {
    if (vars.get('AUDIT_CONTEXT_KEY_' + it) == '1') {
        if (vars.get('EVENT_LOG_ID_' + it) != '48144960') {
            AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
        }
    }
})
```